# Accessing array elements within a session object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, httpcontext

I have a session object in my c# class, that contains an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) type of data. How can I access the array within the session object?

Given the image below, how would I access _confNum value?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpSession is a key-object store.
C# is strongly typed, you need to cast the result of the []-accessor.

```
TripAssignment[] logs = (TripAssignment[])HttpContext.Current.Session["DriverTripLog"];
TripAssignment log = logs[0];
```

By the way, you shouldnt use ArrayList, if possible.

```
ArrayList logs = (ArrayList)HttpContext.Current.Session["DriverTripLog"];
TripAssignment log = (TripAssignment)logs[0];
```

Comment: on your first line, I am getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'TripAssignment[]'

Comment: That's the compilers answer to your question. *fixed*

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it.

```
ArrayList myAL = (ArrayList)Session["DriverTripLog"];

TripAssessment myObj = myAL[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = Session["DriverTripLog"]!=null? (ArrayList)Session["DriverTripLog"]:null;
```